# $_post variable foreach loop logic problem

Tags: php

This code should check the input if it's found in the array, but it does not. It just works for the first index [0]

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "joe",
    "sarah",
    "jaison",
    "klai",
    "hanna"
);
if ($_POST){
    foreach($array as $value){
        echo $value;
        if($_POST["name"] == $value){
            echo "yeb,i know him !";
            break;
        } else {
            echo "i dont know him";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
<p>please enter a name</p>
<form method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="go!">
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: *"it just works for the first index"* ... that's what you're telling it to do by putting `break` into your loop.

Comment: Don't use `break`

Comment: So remove the `break`, [did you look up what a break does?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: you want to remove the `break` from your `else` part. why? as all other guys mentioned, `break` **breaks** the loop right after the first iteration.

Comment: i knew its a break might be the problem but i want it to break once it found the name   and when iinput another name it loops again !

Comment: ok got it ,my bad ,thank you all

Answer (score 3):

1.Use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead of [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

2.Directly check posted name is empty or not.

3.Remove `break;`

```
<?php
$array=array("joe","sarah","jaison","klai","hanna");
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    // add true as 3rd parameter to in_array if you want to check types as well
    if(in_array($_POST['name'] ,$array)){
        echo "yeb,i know him !";
    }else{
        echo "i dont know him";
    }
}
?>
<p>please enter a name</p>
<form method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="go!">
```

Sample output:- https://3v4l.org/VObsX AND https://3v4l.org/HWkU1

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use a foreach loop here. There is a function `in_array` that checks if an value is present in an array. Look at this example:

```
$array = array("joe", "sarah", "jaison", "klai", "hanna");

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
  if( in_array ($_POST["name"], $array) ) {
    echo "yeb,i know him !";
  } else {
    echo "i dont know him";
  }
}

?>
<p>please enter a name</p>
<form method="post">
  <input name="name" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="go!">
</form>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use strict mode for `in_array()` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in_array() function for it. Like this way:

```
$array=array("joe",
            "sarah",
            "jaison",
            "klai",
            "hanna");

if ($_POST){
    if(in_array( $_POST["name"], $array )){
        echo "yeb,i know him !";
    }
    else{
        echo "i dont know him";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use strict mode for `in_array()` whenever possible.